# Geting "cannot read property '[method]' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

This may have a simple solution, but I'm just not seeing it.  I'm writing a protractor test and setting a page object file

newstate.js (the page object file)

```
'use strict';

var newstate = function (url) {
    browser.get(url);
};

newstate.prototype = Object.create({}, {
    dd: { select: function(state) { $('select option[value="'+state+'"]').click(); } }
});

module.exports = newstate;
```

The spec.js file:

```
'use strict';

var newstate = require('newstate.js');

describe('Testing newstate', function() {
    var statePage;
    beforeAll(function() {
        statePage = new newstate('http://localhost:8080');
    });

    it('should select a state', function() {
        statePage.dd.select('AK');
    })
})
```

The conf.js file:

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    specs: ['test-spec.js'],
    useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true
    }
};
```

When I run protractor, I get:

```
$ protractor conf.js
Failures:
1) Testing newstate should select a state
  Message:
    Failed: Cannot read property 'select' of undefined
```

It is launching the browser, opening the webpage, just as it should when I've called `new newstate('...')`  But for some reason it doesn't want to see my dd.select function. What am I missing or doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: As a coding convention, it would be better to declare the constructor as `function Newstate(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are using [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) is incorrect. Proper notation in your case would be:

```
var newstate = function (url) {
    browser.get(url);
};

newstate.prototype = Object.create({
    dd: { select: function(state) { $('select option[value="'+state+'"]').click(); } }
});
```

The reason why `select` is undefined on the `dd` object is that the second argument to `Object.create` is a [property descriptor object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties), not just an object with properties like you provided.

However, in your case you don't really need Object.create at all, as `newstate.prototype.dd = function() { /*...*/ }` would be enough.

Comment: I actually have quite a number of functions to put into the prototype. Which would you suggest is the best way? `newstate.prototyp.dd = ...` or use the `Object.create()` method?

Comment: It's better to not use Object.create in this case, as it usually meant to setup inheritance, not just prototype. So no benefit from it here. I would just use `newstate.prototype = {constructor: newstate, dd: function() {}, another: function()  {}, ...}`. `constructor: newstate` is to make sure instances of `newstate` has constructor property pointing to original constructor, but this might not be very important.